# Center lightbox window and make it responsive

Tags: jquery

I've created this simple JQuery code for lightbox slideshow project.
So far it's going well, but I would like you to please help me make this window reponsive?

What's the math/code to make it so?

Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.lightbox').click(function(){
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
      });

      $('.close').click(function(){
        close_box();
      });

      $('.backdrop').click(function(){
        close_box();
      });

    });

    function close_box()
    {
      $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
      });
    }
```

```css
body
  {
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  }

  .backdrop
  {
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:#000;
   opacity: .0;
   filter:alpha(opacity=0);
   z-index:50;
   display:none;
  }


  .box
  {
   position:absolute;
   top:20%;
   left:30%;

   background:#ffffff;
   z-index:51;
   padding:10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
   box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
   display:none;
  }
    .caption {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hasaboo</h1>
 <a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>

 <div class="backdrop"></div>
 <div class="box">

    <img src="http://www.dan-dare.org/FreeFun/Images/PrinceOfPersiaWallpaper21024.jpg" width="500"/>
    <div class="caption">CAPTION!!!!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check code below . you can center the .box and keep its width relative to the width of the image inside by using `left:50%;top:50%;` ( values depending on the width of the parent the absolute box is relative to , in this case the `body` ) and also add `transform:translate(-50%;-50%)` ( values depending on the .box dimensions ) and so it will center vertically and horizontally

plus. add `max-width:100%` on the image to be responsive on different screens.

let me know if this is what you want

check snippet or fiddle [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/dnz6gbkr/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox').click(function() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
      'opacity': '.50'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.box').animate({
      'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    close_box();
  });

  $('.backdrop').click(function() {
    close_box();
  });

});

function close_box() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  }, 300, 'linear', function() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  left: 50%;

  text-align: center;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
}

.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 500px;

}

.caption {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hasaboo</h1>
<a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>

<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="box">

  <img src="http://www.dan-dare.org/FreeFun/Images/PrinceOfPersiaWallpaper21024.jpg" />
  <div class="caption">CAPTION!!!!</div>
</div>
```